# in vscode, can I have the hover information only when press the alt key?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am just getting started with using vscode. I noticed that when I hover the mouse over the text and squiggly  lines, I get some extended information. this can be useful at time, but most often it is distracting. I know how to disable the hover all together using settings (`Editor > Hover: Enabled`), but I want something easier, like enabling hover only when I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key

is it at all possible with vs code. maybe with an extension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As clarified in your comment below, here is another approach.  You will need the [toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.toggle) extension made by one of the vscode team members.  In your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "alt+z",
  // "key": "alt+capslock",

  "command": "toggle",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",

  "args": {
    "id": "hover",
    "value": [
      {
        "editor.hover.enabled": true
      },
      {
        "editor.hover.enabled": false
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Now you push <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> once to turn hover on and you can over over whatever you want, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> again to turn off hover.

[image: hover toggle]

When you toggle it on, you do have to move the mouse ever so slightly to trigger it to show the hover of the thing you are over.  Toggling it off happens immediately.

You still can't use just <kbd>Alt</kbd> because it is a modifier key - and must have something to modify.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_accepted-keys for can be used with a modifier key:  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>capslock</kbd> works for example.

Comment: thats a step in the right direction. the problem is, I have to press alt-z  for each location in the editor that I want the hover to show up. it would be nice just to press and hold once and then hover around with the mouse. how about alt+shift or some other combination?

Comment: I understand better what you want now.  Try the changes I made to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I have a setting like this: ```"[vue]": {
    "editor.hover.enabled": false
  }```, how to toggle this language spcific setting with the toggle extension? VSCode setting page shows this seting id is "@id:editor.hover.enabled @lang:vue hover".